# how to hide error notification in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I tried to hide error notification in Codeigniter.

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
  switch (ENVIRONMENT)
  {
    case 'development':
        ini_set('display_errors', '0');
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(0);
    break;

    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
  }
}
```

But the errors are still showing

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/userindex.php

Line Number: 102

Comment: i set the database config as " $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;"  but database errors are showing

Comment: define the environment just above `ERROR REPORTING` in your `index.php` as `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production')`

Comment: define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');  its already  set like that

Comment: if you set `'db_debug' => FALSE` it will not display database error it is not depended with error reporting. Make sure You are connected with right database config. Also add with your question what Error message you got

Comment: thanks all i got cleared the problem :-)